# Unresolved symbols after building HDF5, netCDF-C and netCDF4-python from source

Tags: python, hdf5, netcdf4

After using the netCDF4-python package without any trouble, I needed to enable parallel file access. As I could not find suitable ready-made combinations of HDF5 and netCDF C libraries built against the same MPI library, I decided to build each of the packages from source with OpenMPI. However, importing the netCDF4 package fails due to unresolved symbols:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 import netCDF4
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netCDF4-1.5.1.2-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/netCDF4/**init**.py
>   in 
>         1 # init for netCDF4. package
>         2 # Docstring comes from extension module _netCDF4.
>   ----> 3 from ._netCDF4 import *
>         4 # Need explicit imports for names beginning with underscores
>         5 from ._netCDF4 import **doc**, **pdoc**
>
> ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libnetcdf.so.15: undefined symbol:
>   H5Pset_dxpl_mpio

I tried installing the netcdf4-python package via pip install, and it imports works fine for serial file access, but still fails to load a file with parallel=True, stating that it requires parallel-enabled netcdf-c.

I am installing HDF5 with

```
export NCPROCS=4
export CC=mpicc
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --enable-parallel --enable-hl
make check
sudo make install
```

and netCDF-C with

```
export NCPROCS=4
export CC=mpicc
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --enable-parallel-tests
make check
sudo make install
```

and netCDF4-python using nc-config with

```
export CC=mpicc
python setup.py install
```

Each step recognizes the parallel functionalities. Am I missing a linking step in the build process somewhere, or why can't libnetcdf.so.15 find the symbols from the HDF5 library?